# Trouble Accessing Ruby Params on RhoMobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, rhomobile, rhodes

I'm new to Ruby so please excuse my ignorance. I really didn't know how to word this question so this may also be part of the reason I haven't found an answer online.

I'm working with Rho Elements, and I'm trying to pass something from one page to another. I've made some good headway but run into something that I do not understand. I can pass through an ID like so

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= @orderdetails.object %>"/>
```

I then grab the ID(only doing this right now to make sure I do get the ID)

```
@id = @params['id']
```

then redirect to another page

```
redirect url_for(:action => :newpage, :id => @id).
```

This is where my problems start. When I debug the application I get past the redirect and enter :newpage

```
def newpage
    @orderdetails = OrderDetails.find(@params['id'])
    if @orderdetails
      render :action => :newpage, :back => url_for(:action => :index)
    else
      redirect :action => :index
    end
end
```

Once here I check

```
@params['id]
```

and this is what is displayed.

```
@params {"id"=>"{131113212443313.17}"}  
"id"    ""
```

@params {"id"=>"{131113212443313.17}"} is shown by eclipse and when I break into the variable "id"  "" is shown.

Why can I see the ID that I want to use to grab the orderdetails that was just created but also have the actual variable be empty?

**EDIT: This is the information I'm trying to pass.

```
@params {"id"=>"131113212443313.17", "next"=>"asleftnext", "orderdetails"=>
{"AsFoundMeterRead"=>"", "AsFoundImage"=>""}}   
"id"    "131113212443313.17"    
"next"  "asleftnext"    
"orderdetails"  {"AsFoundMeterRead"=>"","AsFoundImage"=>""}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `params` in the controller, not `@params`. Also the canonical form of accessing keys is `params[:id]`.

Comment: Extra information: the `params` hash is actually an instance of `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` which allows you to access the hash with either a symbol or String key.

Comment: @harm Thanks but I'm still getting nil. I'm going to update quickly with some additional info that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Like its say in the previous answer you access the params in the controller in this way

```
@id = params[:id]
```

Also if you are using Rails 3 or higher you may want to use the new url way is less verbose so its more easy to read.

```
newpage_controllername_url(:id => @id)
```

you can also ask for the path with this method.

If you don't know if you are passing right the params you can display the content using

```
params.inspect
```

You can view the content of any object with inspect

Comment: Thanks I'm using eclipse to debug the application and I can see the value is indeed being passed via :id => @id but I'm having trouble getting it out of params.

Comment: I'm a little confused with the your flow but why don't you try to use sessions if you want to pass values from one view to another. If you already changed your `@params` for `params` there must be something wrong in the flow of the redirects. 

I tested in my application `@params.inspect` and its empty.

You can access session just calling the method and adding a key

`session[:id] = @id` 
 but if you don't have the configuration for using the db session store, the session will be saved in a cookie so it will be limited to cookies size and you shouldn't store sensitive data there

Comment: I'm using the Rhodes framework which does not support sessions. I think I need to understand more about the framework/ruby before I can begin to understand what is happening. Thanks for the answer but I think it is going to require more digging on my part.

Comment: Some more updated info: I've found out that when I try to access the :id from the params it is adding on ellipses so my :id is actually {123456789} rather than 123456789. My assumption is that this means it is an array and I need to access like an array. Would that be correct? EDIT: It is a hash my mistake.